# Pandas: Why is default column type for numeric float?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, nan, na

I am using Pandas 0.18.1 with python 2.7.x. I have an empty dataframe that I read first. I see that the types of these columns are `object` which is OK. When I assign one row of data, the type for numeric values changes to `float64`. I was expecting `int` or `int64`. Why does this happen?

Is there a way to set some global option to let Pandas knows that for numeric values, treat them by default as `int` unless the data has a `.`? For example, `[0 1.0, 2.]`, first column is `int` but other two are `float64`?

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', engine='python', keep_default_na=False)
>>> print df.dtypes
bbox_id_seqno    object
type             object
layer            object
ll_x             object
ll_y             object
ur_x             object
ur_y             object
polygon_count    object
dtype: object
>>> df.loc[0] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> print df.dtypes
bbox_id_seqno     object
type              object
layer             object
ll_x             float64
ll_y             float64
ur_x             float64
ur_y             float64
polygon_count    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible for Pandas to store `NaN` values in integer columns.

This makes `float` the obvious default choice for data storage, because as soon as missing value arises Pandas would have to change the data type for the entire column. And missing values arise very often in practice.

As for *why* this is, it's a restriction inherited from Numpy. Basically, Pandas needs to set aside a particular bit pattern to represent `NaN`. This is straightforward for floating point numbers and it's defined in the IEEE 754 standard. It's more awkward and less efficient to do this for a fixed-width integer.

***Update***

Exciting news in pandas 0.24. IntegerArray is an experimental feature but might render my original answer obsolete. So if you're reading this on or after 27 Feb 2019, check out [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntegerArray.html) for that feature.

Answer (score 4):

If you are reading an empty dataframe, you can explicitly cast the types for each column after reading it.

```
dtypes = {
    'bbox_id_seqno': object,
    'type': object,
    'layer': object,
    'll_x': int,
    'll_y': int,
    'ur_x': int,
    'ur_y': int,
    'polygon_count': int
}


df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', engine='python', keep_default_na=False)

for col, dtype in dtypes.iteritems():
    df[col] = df[col].astype(dtype)

df.loc[0] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> df.dtypes
bbox_id_seqno    object
type             object
layer            object
ll_x              int64
ll_y              int64
ur_x              int64
ur_y              int64
polygon_count     int64
dtype: object
```

If you don't know the column names in your empty dataframe, you can initially assign everything as an `int` and then let Pandas sort it out.

```
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 3):

The why is almost certainly to do with flexibility and speed. Just because Pandas has only seen an integer in that column  so far doesn't mean that you're not going to try to add a float later, which would require Pandas to go back and change the type for all that column. A float is the most robust/flexible numeric type.

There's no global way to override that behaviour (that I'm aware of), but you can use the `astype` method to modify an individual DataFrame.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html