# Why does Pandas DataFrame function infer float64 which can be downcast to float32

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am starting a large matrix which I convert to dataframe in pandas allowing pandas to infer the data type of the columns.

The columns are inferred as float64, but I am subsequently able to downcast these columns to float32 using the pandas `to_numeric` function without a loss of precision.

Why is pandas inefficiently inferring the columns as float64 if they are able to be downcast to float32 without a loss of precision?

```
a = np.matrix('0.1 0.2; 0.3 0.4')
a_df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(np.ravel, a)), dtype=None)
print(genotype_data_df.dtypes)
# the columns are float64
genotype_data_df = a_df.apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float')
# the columns are now float32
```

I am assuming that there is an underlying technical or practical reason why the library is implemented in this way? If so I am expecting an answer which would explain why this is the case.

Comment: Because you are explicitly saying that you are willing to lose precision there?

Comment: Generally, "Why does X library implement Y in this way, rather than in some other way?" can be answered "Because that's how X implements Y".  What type of *answer* are you expecting here?

Comment: @DavidZemens I am assuming that there is an underlying technical or practical reason why the library is implemented in this way? If so I am expecting an answer which would explain why this is the case.

Comment: The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003406/pandas-why-is-default-column-type-for-numeric-float) seem to get at what you're asking. Basically, the default type here is not so much of an "inference", it's just a default type when [receiving floats/integers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), so it's done at maximum precision to avoid redundancy and to avoid loss of precision. IOW, when the required precision is unknown, it would seem safer/better to assume a greater (rather than lesser) degree of precision.

Comment: NB: you're *not* downcasting to int32, but float32.

Comment: NB: `downcast='int'` raises an error. You need `downcast='integer'` and while that does not result in a loss of precision, if you do `a_df.dtypes` you'll observe that the columns are still `float64`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Why is default column type for numeric float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003406/pandas-why-is-default-column-type-for-numeric-float)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is pandas inefficiently inferring the columns as int64

It's not clear to me that the cast to `int64` is inefficient. This is simply the *default* `dtype` for numeric values which avoids redundancy in re-casting the column to a higher precision as would be required by examining *every* value in the column in order to assign the proper `dtype`.

Why did they implement it that way instead of say, as `integer` or `float32`? Because if any value in the column exceeds that default precision, then the entire column needs to be re-cast to a greater precision, and to do that would require examining every single value in the column. So it is less redundant/expensive to just assume the higher precision from the start, rather than examine every value and re-cast etc.

Of course this may not seem "optimal", but this is a tradeoff you have to make if you're not able to specify a `dtype` for the constructor.

> they are able to be downcast to int32 without a loss of precision?

You're mistaken about this. There is apparently no loss of precision, but if you check your `genotype_data_df.dtypes`, you'll see that they haven't been cast to a lower precision (integer), in fact they remain as `float64`.

```
>> a = np.matrix('0.1 0.2; 0.3 0.4')
>> a_df = DF(list(map(np.ravel, a)), dtype=None)
>> genotype_data_df = a_df.apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer')
>> genotype_data_df.dtypes

0    float64
1    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Apologies seems like I made a mistake in my example code.
So you're suggesting that python is assuming float64 to avoid the computationally expensive process of checking for potential loss of precision when casting as float32?

Comment: It's casting to float64 because that's the default for numeric type. Why is it the default? Because that's how they implemented it. Why did they implement it that way instead of say, as `integer` or `float32`? Because if any value in the column exceeds the default precision, then the entire column needs to be re-cast to a greater precision, and to do that would require examining every single value in the column. So it is less redundant/expensive to just assume the higher precision from the start, rather than examine every value and re-cast etc.