# Custom pandas dtype inferring

Tags: python, pandas, casting, type-inference

I'm processing multiple big .csv files with each having a numerous and different variables, and possibly more of them will appear in the future.

Problem is, the way pandas infer types by default doesn't match my needs.
For instance, numerical variables for which some rows have no value end up being interpreted as float64, even when they're meant to be used as integer.

I'd like for instance to prioritize Int64Dtype over float64, without having to manually make a huge dtypes dictionary.

A dirty solution would be to read the .csv, check each variable with my own algorithm to constitute a dtypes dictionary of my own and reopen the .csv with the dictionary or alter each variable.

I wondered if there was a simple way to use a custom inferring or even just set up a different order for dtype checking but haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am wondering if [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)'s `dtype` parameter is not what you are looking for? You can specify the types of columns using dictionary of column names to types as a parameter.

Another approach is to use trial and error approach in conversion of `float64` columns:

```
for col, dtype in df.dtypes:
   if dtype == 'float64':
       try:
           df[col] = df[col].as_type('int64')
       except ValueError:
           pass
```

There are also 2 possibilities provided by provided by `pandas`:

You can do the same as above using [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) Series method which downcasts the type to the smallest possible given the data:

```
for col, dtype in df.dtypes:
   df[col] = df[col].to_numeric(downcast='integer')
```

Similarly, you can use [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.convert_dtypes.html) to convert both ints and floats at the same time:

```
for col, dtype in df.dtypes:
   df[col] = df[col].convert_dtypes(convert_integer=True, convert_floating=True, convert_string=False, convert_boolean=False)
```

For the curious:

The reason `pandas` insists on using floating types is [possibility to represent missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003406/pandas-why-is-default-column-type-for-numeric-float).

Comment: That's what I want to avoid, as I'd have to make the dictionary in the first place, which would need to be updated if done manually when new variables get added (and there are already a lot of them), or would require a first read of the .csv file if done algorithmically.

Comment: @Uretki: Does any of the other approaches fit your needs?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking for something closer to what 정성헌 suggested to change the parser behavior for type guessing, but in a more natural way like using an obscure parameter I'd have missed while searching, instead of altering existing code. In the end I'll stick to your solution, which still fills the needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change algorithm

You have to go to the position when the method exist.

The position can be known by the code

```
import pandas
import inspect
import os
os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(pandas.read_csv))
```

Maybe it will return ~/~/~/~/~/lib/site-packages/pandas/io

You go into the parsers.py and find the code

```
from pandas import Int64Dtype # it have to added

def _infer_types(self, values, na_values, try_num_bool=True):
    """
    Infer types of values, possibly casting

    Parameters
    ----------
    values : ndarray
    na_values : set
    try_num_bool : bool, default try
       try to cast values to numeric (first preference) or boolean

    Returns
    -------
    converted : ndarray
    na_count : int
    """
    na_count = 0
    if issubclass(values.dtype.type, (np.number, np.bool_)):
        mask = algorithms.isin(values, list(na_values))
        na_count = mask.sum()
        if na_count > 0:
            if is_integer_dtype(values):
                values = values.astype(Int64Dtype())  #after change 
                #values = values.astype(np.float64)     #before change
            np.putmask(values, mask, np.nan)
        return values, na_count
```

Maybe it will be resolve your problem